# ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped stopped working after an update from update manager

Tags: unity

I had installed unity-revamped from PPA as per Omgubuntu's instructions and all was working fine until I installed a few updates from update manager and now the Ubuntu launcher doesn't hide.

How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open CCSM and set it to dodge windows behavior.

[image: Then open CCSM and set it to your favorite behavior!]

Comment: Thanks it worked!

I'm guessing that the CCSM got reset after an update from ppa:ikarosdev/unity-revamped PPA.

Thanks for your quick reply :)

Comment: Ravi, makes sure to vote on this solution as the correct one. Thanks @Srinivas Gowda for the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help. The reason I know the fix is cause I faced the same problem a few hours back. And I quickly checked with ccsm settings and restored the windows dodge property.